# ObservableCollection CollectionChanged event problum

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

When ever I add a new item to the `ObservableCollection` `CollectionChanged` event is working perfectly,

Here is **MVVM Code**

```
public List<BOMForDesignMasterModel> BOMCollection { get; set; } 

public ObservableCollection<BOMForDesignMasterModel> BOM
    {
        get { return _BOM; }
        set
        {
            _BOM = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("BOM");
            BOM.CollectionChanged += BOM_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }
public DesignMasterModel DesignMaster
    {
        get
        {
            return _DesignMaster;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                _DesignMaster = value;
                BOM.Clear();
                BOM = new ObservableCollection<BOMForDesignMasterModel>(BOMCollection.Where(x => x.DesignMasterId == value.DesignMasterId));
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DesignMaster");
            }
        }
    }
void BOM_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (BOMForDesignMasterModel item in e.NewItems)
                item.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (BOMForDesignMasterModel item in e.OldItems)
                item.PropertyChanged -= item_PropertyChanged;

    }
    public String TotalWeight { get { return _TotalWeight; } set { _TotalWeight = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalWeight"); } }
    void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Weight")
        {
            TotalWeight = BOM.Sum(x => x.Weight).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Here am using copy collection based on condition,

```
BOM = new ObservableCollection<BOMForDesignMasterModel>(BOMCollection.Where(x => x.DesignMasterId == value.DesignMasterId));
```

when I did like this item_PropertyChanged event not working of copied items.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: are you actually registering for BOM_CollectionChanged anywhere?  i don't see it, but you obviously haven't included instrumental parts of the code.

Comment: Why all the registering.  In the set of BOMForDesignMasterModel Weight just call NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalWeight ");  And have that get calculate the total weight.

Comment: @SamAlex not sure I understand your problem but when you create the list it will not raise `CollectionChanged` event for items you pass in constructor because a) it doesn't need to b) no `CollectionChanged` event handler is yet assigned. Basically in the setter of `BOM` property, where you assign `CollectionChanged` handler, list is already fully created and has initial items in it

Comment: Just a small point, but each time the `BOM` setter is called you are registering a handler against the collection being assigned, but it seems that you're not removing the registered handler from the current value, i.e. `_BOM`. It is good practice to remove unwanted handlers otherwise you could run into the situation where objects are not being GCed because of event handler references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your problem:

```
BOM = new ObservableCollection<BOMForDesignMasterModel>(BOMCollection.Where(x => x.DesignMasterId == value.DesignMasterId));
```

When you new up an ObservableCollection like this you're not changing its *contents*, which would fire NotifyPropertyChanged. You're changing the *instance* of ObservableCollection, which doesn't.

While you can't just new up the ObservableCollection you can use Clear/Add/Remove to alter its contents as required. To prevent your setter from getting too cluttered I'd recommend moving that logic out into its own method and finding some other way to trigger it.

That would look something like this:

```
private void RefreshBOM(int designMasterId)
{
    BOM.Clear();
    var bomResult = BOMCollection.Where(x => x.DesignMasterId == designMasterId);
    if(bomResult != null)
    {
        foreach(var result in bomResult)
        {
            BOM.Add(result);
        }
    }
}
```